# Links with dropdown menus don't show up, links without dropdown menus still work

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

Somehow the links with dropdown menus no longer show a dropdown when you mouse over. The links without any dropdowns still work fine. It happens on [this website](http://www.theplanter.nl) with the links on the green navbar and I have no clue what could possibly cause this to happen. I have not changed a single script on the website except for some CSS. I haven't changed any classes or ID's either and it happens on all browsers. If this helps, I'm using OpenCart which uses a theme based on bootstrap.

Comment: You added `overflow` to your `.navbar` menu, the dropdowns are now overflowed (see the little scrollbar appearing on the navigation right edge?) Remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove overflow-x: hidden; in line number 397 in stylesheet.css

```css
.navbar {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}
```

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

remove the overflow from the navbar

```
.navbar {
  max-width: 100%;
   /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}
```

if it does not work add z-index to the list like so

```
.listclass{
z-index: 2;
}
```